# tanstack / react-query : queries being re-fetched even though they're cached & 'fresh'

Tags: javascript, axios, query-string, react-query

I'm using react-query v3, and encountered this problem when implementing backend pagination:

I have this `useQuery` hook in charge of caching `getJobs` which might be called with filters/ sorting/ paginated query parameters.

```
 useQuery(
    ['jobs', activePage, limit, search, statusQuery, sortByQuery?.sort_by, sortByQuery?.order_by],
    () => HttpClient.getJobs(activePage, limit, search, statusQuery, sortByQuery?.sort_by, sortByQuery?.order_by),
    {
        retry: false,
        staleTime: DATA_REFRESH_INTERVAL_MS,
        refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
        keepPreviousData: true, // This tells React-Query that this Query is part of a paginated component
    },
)
```

on my httpClient I use `axios` along with `qs` where I send all parameters serialized with `skipNulls` set to true, so all null/ empty values won't be sent.

so for example, when the page loads, first request being sent is `/api/jobs?page=1&limit=7&search=job_1`

looking into query dev tools I realized that my queries are cached, but also noticed in the network tab that my queries are being re-fetched even though they're in 'fresh' mode (to my understanding, only 'stale' queries should be re-fetched).

[image]

why is that? It got me thinking that maybe i'm not using the query keys right.

would appreciate any help with best practices / examples/ explanations

Comment: i'm using it's `paramsSerializer` for some extra manipulation 

`paramsSerializer: (params) => qs.stringify(params, { arrayFormat: 'repeat', skipNulls: true })`

this is to specify the format of the output array to: `'a=b&a=c'` given
`{ a: ['b', 'c'] }`

Comment: In your screenshots I see nothing about queries being refetched, could you add info about that? Even better if you could make a reproduction on https://codesandbox.io/, you can use some online api like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/

Comment: hey @Danila thanks for the comment, I was thinking about this too but unfortunately I can't implement this with jsonplacholder as they don't support sorting, ordering or search filters (only 1 search parameter, and that's not the case described above)

Comment: It does not matter whether api supports it or not, just pass this params as key as you do in your example, the only thing you need to reproduce is that given the same set of params your query is refetched for some reason. Or add this info in the post, like I said before. Currently there is one screenshot that shows 3 different queries and no indication that query with same key was refetched